# WPF Get Image inside drawing

Tags: wpf, drawing

I'm using an Image control inside a simple canvas and I allow final user to draw some line (free hand) through Line wpf object.

When user ends his draw I would be able to get the image inside the design (such as a crop image).

Any idea?